Manipulate Properties of Files in Working Directory
I am trying to import a (multi sheet) "xlsb" file into R. Normally, I would have done this using the readxlsb library, e.g. How to open an .xlsb file in R? , but I can not install this library on my school/university computer.
I realized I can manually change the format from xlsb to xlsx, and then use the readxl::read_excel function to import this (How to import multiple xlsx sheets in R)
This got me thinking - using the system() command, is it possible to change the format of the xlsb file directly in R ... and then use the readxl library in R to import?
For example, I know in R its possible to delete a file from the working directory:
a = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,100,100), b = rnorm(100,100,100))
write.csv(a, "Test.csv")

wd <- getwd()
file_path <- file.path(wd, "Test.csv")

file.remove(file_path)

Is it also possible to change the format of a file situated in the working directory?
EDIT: Alternate Way? (inspired from Quinten's answer)
install.packages("openxlsx")
install.packages("readxl")
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)


a <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 100, 100), b = rnorm(100, 100, 100))

write.csv(a, "Test.csv")

data <- read.csv("Test.csv")
write.xlsx(data, "Test.xlsx")

convert_to_xlsb <- function(xlsx_file, xlsb_file) {
  wb <- loadWorkbook(xlsx_file)
  saveWorkbook(wb, xlsb_file, overwrite = TRUE)
}

convert_to_xlsb("Test.xlsx", "Test.xlsb")

convert_xlsb_to_xlsx <- function(xlsb_file, xlsx_file) {
  wb <- loadWorkbook(xlsb_file)
  saveWorkbook(wb, xlsx_file, overwrite = TRUE)
}

convert_xlsb_to_xlsx("Test.xlsb", "Test_converted.xlsx")


Yes, you can create a VBScript script, which does the converting. Then you call this script from R
ConvertXLSBtoXLSX.vbs
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel, objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objWorkbook
Dim inputFolder, outputFile
Dim fileExtension

' Get the folder path from command line arguments
inputFolder = WScript.Arguments(0)

' Create FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create Excel Application object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False ' Do not show Excel window
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False ' Suppress prompts to automatically overwrite files

' Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(inputFolder)

' Loop through each file in the folder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    fileExtension = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name))
    ' Check if the file is a .xlsb file
    If fileExtension = "xlsb" Then
        ' Open the .xlsb file
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
        
        ' Define output file path with .xlsx extension
        outputFile = objFSO.BuildPath(inputFolder, objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.Name) & ".xlsx")
        
        ' Save the file as .xlsx
        objWorkbook.SaveAs outputFile, 51 ' 51 is the file format for .xlsx
        
        ' Close the workbook
        objWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next

' Quit Excel Application
objExcel.Quit

' Clean up
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

convert.R
script <- "path/to/script/ConvertXLSBtoXLSX.vbs"
path <- "path/to/xlsb/folder"
system2("cscript", args = c(shQuote(script), shQuote("//NoLogo"), shQuote(path)))

Of course you want to add some more checks (e.g. is the input path existing) and decide what to do, if there is already a xlsx file of the same name (here I overwrite w/o asking), but this should get you started.

If I understand you correctly, you could check the files in your current working directory based on their extension using list.files. After that use a simple gsub to get the new names of your files and use the file.rename function to change the names of your files in your current working directory with new extension like this:
a = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,100,100), b = rnorm(100,100,100))
write.csv(a, "Test.csv")

your_files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
new_extension <- gsub(".csv$", ".xlsx", your_files)

file.rename(your_files, new_extension)

Created on 2024-08-12 with reprex v2.1.0

@ Quinten: thank you for your reply! Will this work for xlsb files as well? (i.e. convert xlsb to xlsx)?

When @stats_noob said he could "manually change" from xlsb to xlsx, I think he meant open Excel, read the file, then save in a new format.  Simply changing the extension is insufficient.
